# Imshow() doesnt work in stitching_detailed.cpp opencv

Tags: opencv, imshow, opencv-stitching

I added `imshow("result",result)` at the end of opencv sample (stitching_detailed.cpp) which is in opencv source files, But it doesnt show image . 
if I save it to .jpg and then reopen it using imread it will work fine.
does anybody know why?
this code save file in result.jpg but doesnt show image!! Strange!

`imwrite("result.jpg", result);
    namedWindow("resultwindow", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("resultwindow", result);
    waitKey(0);`

The code below will show the image, but time is important for me I don't wanna save file and then read it (My project is real time stitching)

```
imwrite(result_name, result);
Mat result2=imread("result.jpg");
namedWindow("resultwindow", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("resultwindow", result2);
waitKey(0);
```

It's really strange. try it . you will see , Please anybody help me where is wrong?!! how to show stitched image in stitching_Detailed.cpp?

Comment: add a `waitKey(some_millis);` after the imshow, else nothing will be drawn to it.

Comment: I did add waitkey(0) and waitkey(5000) ,both didnt worked

Comment: I think maybe imwrite do sth to "Mat result" to be showable and savable that imshow doesnt do this .Is it?

Comment: Try it yourself in the mentioned code. Its really a bug . I did work a lot with  imshow in showing real-time projects but never seen this before in other codes! something is special with this Matrix that imshow cant show it

Comment: Try using WINDOW_AUTOSIZE  instead of WINDOW_NORMAL. Just to be sure. Indeed, I think you could omit your cvNamedWindow statements. At least, use namedWindow instead. Probably not a solution but could narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: didnt work with too .
 namedWindow("resultwindow", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
Can you test it ? I think Its a Bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that's not a bug. `result` is a 3 channel matrix of `int16`, and you cannot display it with `imshow` (it shows a gray image).

Just convert it to a regular Mat3b like:

```
Mat3b visibleResult;
convertScaleAbs(result, visibleResult);
imshow("visibleResult", visibleResult);
waitKey();
```

and you should be able to see it.

Hope it helps!